# Compiling Portable UPnP Library for Windows Phone 8.1 or 10

Tags: c++, c, windows-phone-8.1, windows-10-mobile, upnp

I need to compile a Portable UpnP library (http://pupnp.sourceforge.net/) for Windows Phone 8.1 or 10.

The library can be compiled in x86 Windows 10 and one person (https://github.com/atraczyk/libupnp) has already created the missing the VS 2015 project files for the library. I used this version and changed the project target to ARM and did several other changes like the following.

- I have compiled pthread-win32 (https://github.com/GerHobbelt/pthread-win32) against ARM Processor and it was successful.
- I have done some changes and tweaks in the library to make it work.

And, I successfully accomplished to compile pthread-win32, ixml and threadutil projects.

**However**; The actual project, libupnp, didn't compile because of missing iphlpapi library in Windows Phone environment. I searched online and stackoverflow. And I couldn't find any solution to compile the library without iphlpapi or with a replacement of it. I hope you can guide me on how to compile the library.

**TL;DR**

Is there any way that I can include iphlpapi library to a Windows Phone 8.1 ARM project to compile the Portable UPnP library for Windows Phone 8.1 ARM based device.

*Clarification*, I am sticking with this version of the UPnP even though I know there are alternatives. Because, other platforms (Android and iOS) are using this library and there is a common C code that we need to use in all platforms. So, changing the library is not an obvious solution.

Comment: I see a "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Lib\winv6.3\um\arm\IPHlpApi.Lib" on my system. Can't you link it against this lib? or is this lib only for Windows RT (SurfaceRT)?

Comment: Exactly, it is right there in my environment as well. How come I missed it. Thank you very much for pointing it out. When I added the header file as well that is in C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um. It compiled it. Then, I had some other errors though. If you write this as an answer, I will accept it. However; I still didn't get why VS didn't recognize the library automatically as it is doing for win32 version of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see an ARM lib of the `IPHlpApi.Lib` on my system at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Lib\winv6.3\um\arm\IPHlpApi.Lib`. Add this to the linker option of the solution.